# How to use c++11 std::thread to implement a QThread-like class?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, qthread

`std::thread` is not simply inheritable by classes, cannot auto join when destruction, etc.

Lots of pitfalls like need to use `std::atomic_bool` for stopping, cannot simply share `this` of object when use `std::thread` as member variables to execute a member method.

Is there any good practice to implement QThread like classes using `std::thread`?

---

I'm aiming at an inheritable Thread class, enables `start()`, `detach()`, `stop()` functionality.

For example I wrote one like the following:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

struct Thread {
  Thread(int id) {
    std::atomic_init(&(this->id), id);
    std::atomic_init(&(this->m_stop), false);
  }

  Thread(Thread &&rhs) :
    id(),
    m_stop(),
    m_thread(std::move(rhs.m_thread))
  {
    std::atomic_init(&(this->id), rhs.id.load());
    rhs.id.store(-1);
    std::atomic_init(&(this->m_stop), rhs.m_stop.load());
  }

  virtual ~Thread() {
    this->stop();
  }

  void start() {
    this->m_thread = std::move(std::thread(&Thread::work, this));
  }

  void stop() {
    this->m_stop.store(true);

    if (this->m_thread.joinable()) {
      this->m_thread.join();
    }
  }

  virtual void work() {
    while (!(this->m_stop)) {
      std::chrono::milliseconds ts(5000);
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(ts);
    }
  }

  std::atomic_int id;
  std::atomic_bool m_stop;
  std::thread m_thread;
};


int main() {
  srand(42);

  while (true) {
    std::vector<Thread> v;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      auto t = Thread(i);
      v.push_back(std::move(t));
      printf("Start %d\n", i);
      v[i].start();
    }
    printf("Start fin!\n");

    int time_sleep = rand() % 2000 + 1000;
    std::chrono::milliseconds ts(time_sleep);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(ts);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      printf("Stop %d\n", i);
      v[i].stop();
      printf("Pop %d\n", i);
      v.pop_back();
    }
    printf("Stop fin!\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

But I'm having a hard time getting it right, just after `Stop 0` it deadlocked, or sometimes it core dumps.

Comment: encapsulate it.

Comment: Cannot auto-join on destruction? Then inherit from it, and make it auto-join on destruction! There's a reason why this is not the case, which is becasue there's another option, namely `detach()`! You can customize everything with inheritance.

Comment: access this concurrently may cause data race, how to solve it then?

Comment: @Richard Hodges, that's why I asked how. You need to elaborate.

Comment: The source code for QThread is visible and I suspect they are also using std::thread.. why do you just start from that..

Comment: @Macro I am, though. Most answers in stackoverflow is wrong currently. They either handled stop incorrectly, either did not handle this, or not providing code at all

Comment: You will have to be clearer.  What exactly about `QThread` do you want?  The Qt message loop?  Inheritance from QObject?  There are *lots* of properties that QThread has, you are asking us to read your mind to even understand your question!

Comment: Do you care about all functionality? Especially the functions about stack size and priority are hard to implement.

Answer (score 2):

`std::thread` is intended as the lowest building block for implementing a threading primitive. As such, it does not offer as rich an interface as QThread, but together with the synchronization primitives from the standard library, it allows you to implement more complex behavior like what's offered by QThread very easily.

You correctly noted that inheriting from `std::thread` is a bad idea (the absence of a virtual destructor is a dead giveaway) and I would argue that having a polymorphic Thread type is not the smartest design in the first place, but you can easily encapsulate a `std::thread` as a member of any class (polymorphic or not) if you want to.

Joining on destruction is really just a policy. A class encapsulating a `std::thread` as a member can simply call `join` in its destructor, effectively implementing self-joining on destruction. Concurrency is of no concern here, as object destruction is always executed non-concurrently, by definition. If you want to share ownership of a thread between multiple (possible concurrently invoked) execution paths, `std::shared_ptr` will handle that for you. But even here, the destructor is always executed non-concurrently by the last remaining thread that gives up its `shared_ptr`.

Stuff like `QThread::isInterruptionRequested` can be implemented with a single flag, access to which of course must be synchronized by the class (either with a mutex or by using an atomic flag).

Changing a thread's priority is not specified by the standard, as not all platforms envisioned by the standard would allow this, but you can use [`native_handle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle) to implement this yourself using platform-specific code.

And so on. All the pieces are there, you just have to assemble them according to your needs.